# DEFUNs inside a LET - why?

Tags: common-lisp

I was reading the source for [ChanL](https://github.com/zkat/chanl) the other day. It contains an example use of channels, to implement futures. The DEFUNs were declared inside a LET, [like so](https://github.com/zkat/chanl/blob/master/examples/futures.lisp):

```
(let ((some-var some-value))
  (defun foo () ... (reference some-var) ... )
  (defun bar () ...))
```

What purpose does this serve? Is it just to provide some common value that several functions can share, and keep the encapsulation clean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already answered your question: to provide shared bindings for a group of functions and keep encapsulation clean.

Simple example from http://letoverlambda.com/textmode.cl/guest/chap2.html:

```
(let ((direction 'down))
  (defun toggle-direction ()
    (setq direction
          (if (eq direction 'up)
              'down
              'up))))
(toggle-direction)   => UP
(toggle-direction)   => DOWN
(toggle-direction)   => UP
(toggle-direction)   => DOWN
```

You can also add a function inside this closure which behavior depends on direction.

Comment: That referenced chapter makes for some really interesting reading. I'm going to have to buy a copy of Let over Lambda!

Answer (score 2):

Those are just closures. Just for the historical context [[1](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html)],

> Closures play a more conspicuous role in a style of programming
>   promoted by Abelson and Sussman’s classic *Structure and Interpretation
>   of Computer Programs*. Closures are functions with local state. The
>   simplest way to use this state is in a situation like the following:

```
(let ((counter 0))
  (defun new-id () (incf counter))
  (defun reset-id () (setq counter 0)))
```

> These two functions share a variable which serves as a counter. The
>   first one returns successive values of the counter, and the second
>   resets the counter to 0. The same thing could be done by making the
>   counter a global variable, but this way it is protected from
>   unintended references.

[Paul Graham - On lisp](http://www.paulgraham.com/onlisp.html)